No Sound on Huawei MateBook 14 2024 - Dummy Output in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm using a Huawei MateBook 14 2024 with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and I'm having issues with the internal speakers. The sound output is "Dummy Output," and I'm unable to get sound through the laptop's internal speakers. However, my Bluetooth headphones work fine.
Sound card: sof-hda-dsp
CPU: Intel Cor Ultra 7 155H
Any help appreciated!

There is a github repo for fixing sound on some Huawei Matebooks.
First, clone the repository.
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix

Now, enter the directory and install it.
cd huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix
sudo bash install.sh

